# Puppeteer: use the first new page when opening incognito context

Tags: puppeteer

```
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const [page] = await context.pages();
```

Why isn't this code working? The array returned by `pages()` is always empty.
The only way I know to actually open a page is to call `context.newPage()`, <s>which means having an `about:blank` empty page. I would like to avoid that</s>.

Comment: interesting. it seems `browserContext.pages()` behaves differently in an incognito browser context than in the default browser context. I'd raise this question rather on puppeteer's GitHub than on SO. `about:blank` in the 1st tab is normally not a problem from resource usage POV.

Comment: My mistake, the `about:blank` pages I was seeing were actually whole new browser instances, it was a problem with my code. I think we discovered here that `createIncognitoBrowserContext()` does not open a default empty page :)